# How to get highlighting using Spring Data Elasticsearch ElasticsearchRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using a spring ElasticsearchRepository to query Elasticsearch:

```
@Repository
public interface MyDocumentRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyDocument, String>{

}
```

I can successfully run a search query and retrieve a list of elasticsearch results mapped in *MyDocument* bean

```
private final MyDocumentRepository myDocumentRepository;

...

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(queryStringQuery("my query"));
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(query)
        .withPageable(pageable)
        .withHighlightFields(
                new HighlightBuilder.Field("field1"),
                new HighlightBuilder.Field("field2"))
                .build();

Iterable<MyDocument> = myDocumentRepository.search(searchQuery);
```

Although the query sent to elasticsearch and response are correct (I can see the highlight block in the debug log) and results are also appropriate, I do not know how to get the highlight information in my java code.

I would like **not** to use ElasticsearchTemplate and a ResultExtractor to get the highlight information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning additional information in an `SearchHit` is a feature implemented in the current master branch which is available in the snaphot build. It will be released with the next release (4.0)

This is not the `SearchHit` class from Elasticsearch but a new introduced class in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

With the current version (3.2.x) this is only possible using a custom result mapper (which will not be available anymore in 4.0)

**Edit:**

As for the configuration in the upcoming version 4, check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest

With this configuration you then can inject an `ElasticsearchOperations` instance into your code, this bean is defined in the `AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration` class. The necessary code fragments:

```
@Autowired ElasticsearchOperations operations;

...

SearchHits<MyDocument> searchHits = operations.search(searchQuery,
                                        MyDocument.class,
                                        IndexCoordinates.of("index-name");
```

As for more information about the returned data check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.searchresulttypes

We know there are quite some deprecations and some breaking changes in version 4.0, but we we'll have a cleaner API and we will have the possibility to return all this search result metadata, this was not possible in 3.2

Comment: I was using curren version 3.2.3. I updated the dependency to 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but now I noticed ElasticsearchRepository search method is deprecated. Also EntityMapper is missing (used in the configuration of ElasticsearchRestTemplate). How should I proceed to query the elasticsearch index with this new spring-data-elasticsearch release? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Acutally if you get the ES response you will have a `SearchHit` Object. This `SearchHit` Object just represents the HTTP Response of the ES result.

If your result hits a highlighted field, the `SearchHit` provides a Map of `Map<String, HighlightField>` where you can iterate and filter your highlighted text and attribute.

Comment: How do I get a SearchHit from ES response?  Calling myDocumentRepository.search(searchQuery) I get a Iterable<MyDocument> but nothing related with a SearchHit